# What are other words for a collection of beautiful things?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, nouns, british-english

I am looking for a word or term for a collection of beautiful things. Of either intrinsic value or even along the lines of 'a whole that is made of a sum of valuable parts'. Not necessarily in any field in particular.

The purpose is for a company name who pride themselves on a beautiful creative company portfolio. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

***[Mirabilia](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/mirabilia)***  is often used to refer to a collection or show of beautiful or unusual things:

> - wonders   ⇒  ■ Such a portrait was a 'must' for a collection of mirabilia.

(Collins Dictionary)

Comment: +1 This could work as a company name, if you don't get sued for trademark infringement.

Answer (score -1):

a trove of things beautiful - poetic inversion sometimes works....
a trove of dazzling creations or works

Comment: Trove is a lovely word, thank you! Mirabilia (below comment) is also nice, although not as sure it rolls off the tounge enough for use as a name. Both appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

A dazzling kaleidoscope of marvels, a bag of wonders, a panopticon of amazing items, a brilliant showcase of awe-inspiring gems.